# Does 私だってわかるくらいに work adverbially in 私の噛む力で私だってわかるくらいに覚えて?

Tags: meaning

> デンジ君。エッチな事はね。相手の事を理解すればするほど気持ちよくなると私は思うんだ。相手の心を理解するのは難しい事だから。最初は手をじっくり観察してみて。指の長さはどれくらい・・・？手のひらは冷たい？温かい？耳の形は？指を噛まれた事はある？かまっ・・・覚えて。デンジ君の目が見えなくなっても。**私の噛む力で私だってわかるくらいに覚えて**。

A female is saying this to a young boy who likes females.

In the last sentence, I believe that 私だってわかるくらいに works adverbially here. My attempt at a translation is:

> Remember my biting force to the extent that I also understand.

Is this correct? If so, what is it that the one saying it want to understand, the her-own-biting-force?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the part before 覚えて adverbially works on 覚えて. However, you are not parsing it right. You should read it this way.

> ［［私の噛む力（だけ）で］［私だって（ことが）］（デンジ君が）わかる］くらいに

First of all, the (semantic) subject (agent) of わかる is the listener, not the speaker.  だって doesn't mean でも in this context. It's the copula だ followed by the quotative って. Therefore, 私だってわかる should be read as 私だということがわかる.

> Remember my biting force (= how strongly I bite) to the extent that you can tell I'm the one biting only by feeling it.